# iOS App submission is rejected as using Game Centre Leaderboards and Achievements but has not submitted for review

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My app has been rejected by Apple for 4 times due to the message they sent:
"Your app is using Game Center Leaderboards and Achievements but you have not submitted the them for review."

My app uses Game Centre for Multiplayer mode, however, it does not have any leaderboards or achievements feature, game centre is simply enabled for multiplayer.

Please see the following screenshot for detail.
[image: iOS app's submission detail]

As you can see, under my app there is no leaderboards or achievements is selected. The only selected game centre option is "Multiplayer compatibility".

In apple's reject email says if I don't use leaderboards or achievements I can turn off game centre, however, as the game need Game Centre for multiplayer, I believe I cannot turn it off.

Under app's "Game Centre" tab in iTunnesConnect, I do have created some leaderboards and achievements, but those are for future updates which is not yet ready in this release. I didnt link those items with my app's submission as the above screenshot indicated.

The following is a screenshot shows the unfinished items I created for leaderboard and achievements. Once again, they are still under development and I didn't link any of them with the current app's submission.

[image: Unfinished leaderboards and achievements]

And if you have a closer look I cannot actually delete every leaderboards as the 1st leaderboard item's delete button is disabled.

As it is getting very close to the app's launch date, it is getting critical. Please advice how can I fix this issue "your app is using Game Center Leaderboards and Achievements but you have not submitted the them for review."

Thank you very much!

The following is the full response from Apple:

> 2.3 - Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected
>   Thank you for your resubmission and for addressing the previous 2.2 issue. However the 2.3 issue is still presented in your app since the Game Center remains enabled for your app but no Game Center features were submitted.
>
> If you intended to implement Game Center features in your app, please revise your app to include these features. Alternatively, you may wish to disable Game Center for your app and remove all Game Center references from your Application Description, What’s New info and screenshots.
>
> 2.3 Details
>
> We still found that your app is using Game Center Leaderboards and Achievements but you have not submitted the them for review.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please submit the Leaderboards and Achievements for review.
>
> - Login to iTunes Connect
> - Click on “My Apps”
> - Select your app
> - Click on “Game Center”
> - Complete the Leaderboards and Achievements set up
> - Select “Done”
> - Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page.
>
> Alternatively, if you do not wish to include Leaderboards and Achievements:
>   - Click the “Disabled/Enabled” button under “Game Center”
>   - Revise your Application Description, What’s New info, previews and/or screenshots to remove any content that refers to the Game Center feature(s).

Comment: Hm...maybe Game Center comes with Achievements and Leaderboards only?

Comment: Thank you @LinusG. for the comment. Leaderboards and achievements are marked as "optional" under itunnesconnect, which I believe it doesn't mean "mandatory".

Answer (score 2):

ok, after contact with Apple, they have now passed my app's submission. No changes required. Game centre can be used without adding leaderboard or achievement if you are using multiplay compatibility.